# Is it possible to do a transaction with active resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

Looking through the [activeresource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) gem I couldn't find any code to handle transactions, similar to a normal activerecord transaction, which rolls back any changes when an error occurs.

Has anybody implemented a transaction on `activeresource`?

Comment: Nope, asking this out of curiosity, when ActiveRecord is very widely used why did you opt for activeresource?

You could perhaps raise your concern as feature request in the gem's GitHub page itself.

Comment: @lunaLovegood `activeresource` is an interface to REST APIs similar to `activerecord`, have you used `activeresource`?

Comment: No I haven't used. What is the advantage of using `activeresource` instead of `activereacord`

Comment: You can treat an API like it's an active record model :)

Comment: Hmm interesting.